# Getting a cell value from another sheet; the cell has a known column number but un-known row number

Tags: excel, row, cells

I’ve conducted an experiment where each participant played three game trials.

The events that the participant has gone through in each trial is logged in an Excel workbook as sheet "Ex1", sheet "Ex2", and sheet "Ex3"

The last non-empty row of each sheet has a score value of the game trial (number of rows varies depending on the number of events that the participant made during the game trial).

The cell that contains the score value has a known column which is (column E), but unknown row number

In a fourth sheet "Summary", I want to type in three cells score1, score2, and score3
Then beneath them, I want to read the score value from the three sheets.

Can anyone help with that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula. It will grab the value from last row in Column E:

```
=INDIRECT("E"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($E:$E<>"")*(ROW(E:E)))))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked in the same sheet that has the data, but I want to read this cell content from another sheet. I tried adding the sheet title between single quotes but it returns zero!          I mean =INDIRECT("E"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX(('Ex1'!$E:$E<>"")*(ROW('Ex1'!E:E)))))

Comment: Try this:
`=INDIRECT("'Ex2'!E"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX(('Ex2'!$E:$E<>"")*(ROW('Ex2'!E:E)))))`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a maximum number of rows per sheet?  If so, set your score value to be that number +1 (to be safe) and use that number as your row marker for the code.

If the score value has a known column, it's also possible to simply move the row from unknown to row 1 and separate it from the entry columns by x number of rows (say, 3 in this case) and use row 1, column H instead of E.

Comment: Thanks Charles! I made a previous comment, but I deleted it coz it seems that I didn't fully understand your answer, but anyways, it's solved now.